# Getting a portion of file as byte[] at a time

Tags: java, android, file, stream, arrays

I'm trying to handle large files by 10MB byte arrays at a time.
I'm trying to get the byte arrays one at a time (not get entire byte array for the huge file and split the byte array, after all the problem was due to memory)

This is what I have so far:

```
private byte[] readFile(File file, int offset) throws IOException
{
    BufferedInputStream inStream = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = null;
    byte[] buf = new byte[1048576];
    int read = 0;

    try
    {
        inStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        long skipped = inStream.skip(offset);
        read = inStream.read(buf);
        if (read != -1)
        {
            outStream.write(buf, 0, read);
            return outStream.toByteArray();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (inStream != null) {try {inStream.close();} catch (IOException e) {}}
        if (outStream != null) {try {outStream.close();} catch (IOException e) {}}
    }

    return null;
```

the parameter `offset` will be in 10MB increments as well.

So the problem I'm having is that, even tho the `skipped` long variable gives me 1048576 bytes skipped, the second 10MB i'm suppose to receive from calling `readFile(file, 1048576)` is the same as the first byte array from the first 10MB. Thus it didn't really skip the first 10MB at all.

What's the problem here? Is there another way of implementing this idea?

Comment: You're not incrementing the offset with the same amount, so next offset will be 2x 1048576. Hence you get the same bytes all the time.

Comment: I am offsetting it correctly though, 2x 1048576 would be the third chunk as the first chunk would have offset 0 right?

Comment: So you're reading the `File` over and over again and incrementing the `offset` variable from outside the method? Could you add the code calling your method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as per user @EJP I revised the code to work efficiently. I am no longer copying to `ByteArrayOutputStream` as I realized that `.toByteArray` actually returns a copy of the read byte array and is very memory inefficient. I also only opens the stream once so the skipping would be unneeded.

```
    int fileLength = (int) file.length();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[fileLength < FILE_UPLOAD_CHUNK_SIZE ?
            fileLength : FILE_UPLOAD_CHUNK_SIZE];
    int bytesRead;
    int readTotal = 0;
    BufferedInputStream inStream = null;
    try
    {
        inStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        do
        {
            bytesRead = inStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
            if (bytesRead == -1)
            {
                continue;
            }
            byte[] finalBuffer;
            if (buffer.length > bytesRead)
            {
                finalBuffer = Arrays.copyOf(buffer, bytesRead);
            }
            else
            {
                finalBuffer = buffer;
            }
            uploadChunk(
                    finalBuffer,
                    mimeType,
                    uploadPath,
                    fileLength,
                    readTotal,
                    readTotal + bytesRead - 1);
            readTotal += bytesRead;
        } while (bytesRead != -1);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (inStream != null)
        {
            inStream.close();
        }
    }
```

The only blemish I have for this code is the way I have to make a new copy of the byte array when the last chunk is less than 10MB. There should be a more efficient way of doing it but this is working fine for me for now.

Answer (score 1):

Redesign the method. At present you are copying byte arrays like its going out of style: once from the buffer to the ByteArrayOutoutStream and again from there to the return value. So you need three of those at once. Change the signature of the method, so that the *caller* provides the byte array as well as the offset, and the stream, and have it return the count. In other words get rid of it altogether and just call FileInputStream.read(buffer, offset, length) from wherever you are calling this.

Comment: The problem with this and the reason I chose to use input and output buffer is that, if say the last chunk is 5MB, and I call `FileInputStream.read(buffer, offset, length)` with length = 10MB, then wouldn't the last chunk return a 10MB byte array with only 5MB of data? Would that affect converting the file to json and uploading via http?

Comment: Yes, and that's why read() returns a length, and that's why Java is full of methods with the signature (byte[], offset, length);